# How do I get the logged-in user wrapper?

Tags: 8, users

In Drupal 7, we are using this code.

```
global $user;
$user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
```

How do I get the logged-in user wrapper in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a User in drupal 8 becomes an entity type: and each **entity type** has **storage class** that enable us to CRUD a specific entity type entities, so in Drupal 8 in order to get a current user field we need to follow this steps :

```php
# step 1 : get current user ( an object represents the current user)
$current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();

# step 2 : get the user entity type storage :
$user_storage  = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user');

#step 3 : Getting specific user entity.
$user = $user_storage->load($current_user->id());

# step 4 : getting a user entity field
$user->name->value();

# (optional step): to Display all available fields
kint( $user->toArray)
```

#### Explanation :

- **step 1:** Get the current active user.
- **step 2:** the  user entity type storage class is: `Drupal\user\UserStorage` which contains a set of methods that enable us to CRUD the user entities ex :

  - **load(2)** : load the user entity that have an id = 2.
  - **loadMultiple([1,5,8])** : loadthe users that have ids = 1 or 5 or 
    8.
- **step 3 :** using the user storage load method to get a specific user entity object, in our case we pass to it current active user id.
- **step 4 :** `$user->{field_name}->{field_property}` you can use `kint( $user->toArray)` to display the lists of fields and each field properties (value , uri ...).

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 already uses PHP classes for entities. You don't use `entity_metadata_wrapper()` anymore.

The code you need in Drupal 8 is the following.

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

$account = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

Alternatively, you could use the following code.

```
$account = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

When possible, the code should use Dependency Injection.

Note that `\Drupal::currentUser()` returns an instance of the [`AccountProxy`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxy.php/class/AccountProxy/8.9.x) class, not an instance of the [`User`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/class/User/8.9.x). The object returned from `\Drupal::currentUser()` doesn't have all the methods the `User` class has, and it doesn't store the values for the fields a User entity has.

#### References

- [Entity API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/group/entity_api/8.9.x) (in particular, the *Loading, querying, and rendering entities* section)